# Activate Security Protocol in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I'm using powershell to generate different reports and then send them trough mail but I'm getting the next Exception:

```
    Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClie 
   nt) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMe 
   ssage
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

So, checking on the internet i just found that in C# it can be solved using the next code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

I would like to know how to do the same in Powershell

EDIT:

Thanks to Theo i got this code:

```
$protocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' ; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $protocols
```

However I'm still getting the same Exception so... i would like to know how to solve this problem. This is happening with some reports randomly in different executions, sometimes all goes fine and sometimes all go into this Exception.

Comment: `$protocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' ; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $protocols`

Comment: Nice! but however I'm getting the same Exception... sad..

Answer (score -1):

Ok i got my answer:

My script to send the email was :

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Send-MailMessage -To $($args[0]) -From $($args[1]) -Subject $($args[2]) -Body $($args[3]) -SmtpServer $($args[4]) -UseSsl -Port "25" -Credential $($args[6]) -Attachments $($args[5]) 
    } -ArgumentList $To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $SMTP, $DestinationExcelFilePath, $mycreds | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Now is:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $protocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' ; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $protocols
        Send-MailMessage -To $($args[0]) -From $($args[1]) -Subject $($args[2]) -Body $($args[3]) -SmtpServer $($args[4]) -UseSsl -Port "25" -Credential $($args[6]) -Attachments $($args[5]) 
    } -ArgumentList $To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $SMTP, $DestinationExcelFilePath, $mycreds | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```